# rpart: node observation and rules

Tags: cart, rpart

I am trying to find out node of observation in decision tree using `rpart`

```
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, method = 'class', data =kyphosis)
summary(fit)
```

Few last lines of `summary(fit)` return:

```
Node number 23: 7 observations
  predicted class=present  expected loss=0.4285714  P(node) =0.08641975
    class counts:     3     4
   probabilities: 0.429 0.571
```

So I conclude there is terminal node/leaf #23:

However `unique(fit$where)` only returns: `9 7 3 8 5`. So there is no terminal node 23.

Using `partykit`, I get similar conclusion:

```
library(partykit)
z.fit <- as.party(fit)
predict(z.fit, kyphosis, type = 'node')
```

What am I missing?

Update, here is node numbers that I am trying to get:
[image]

Comment: I assume, that while building the tree, internaly the nodeids are n*2 and n*2+1 for the left and right child of node n (eg: 11 -> 22, 23). After the tree calculation is complete and the "whole" tree is build, then the nodeids are given in the order, when you go first to the left node and its children, then to the right node and its children.
So the mapping in this case is: 3=4, 5=10, 7=22, 8=23, 9=3

Comment: @JakobGepp Thank you for explanation! Why do we need two different node ids systems: one during construction and one after completion. What is wrong with keeping only one node ids system that one that is used during construction?

Comment: It may be because how some trees are build. For example the 'partykit' package will go trought the tree by going first to the left child and its nodes - so this way the nodeids are in the number of processing the data. An other way would be to go though the tree "levelwise". Maybe internally there is a list with elements for all possible nodes - with higher depth of a tree this will be a lot (2^(depth-1)).
But I understand your problem... I changed the method of how the tree is build up and have now a lot of mapping between nodes to do ;)